# Start Flask server with python

Tags: python, shell, flask, os.system

I wrote a Flask application, and also got it working with the commands that you normaly use to start it.

That means:

```
cd /var/www/BWSWebApp
export FLASK_APP=main.py
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Explanation (row for row):

cd into the directory the main.py file is in.

Export the main.py file.

Run flask server with an IP-address that can be seen in the whole network.

Now I don't want to manually type that in the console every time I want to start the Flask application.
So i thought myself that I could simply write another Python file with the following

```
import os


os.system('cd /var/www/BWSWebApp')
os.system('export FLASK_APP=main.py')
os.system('flask run --host=0.0.0.0')
```

But when i run the file it doesn't starts the server, and in the Python console i also don't see any output.

Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: If you want to run flask server without those command, then you can use app.run(host="0.0.0.0") you need to run the file in which you use this command.

Comment: Ok, it just worked like you described.   Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use app.run() command in the main file like this.

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
      app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

So that when you import the file the server doesn't start.
You can use other parameters like in run function. Like

```
app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at the end of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key' # your app key
    app.debug = True # set to true if you want to enable debug
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000) # change port according to your needs
```

And run via cli just the script:

```
python your_script_name.py
```

Comment: What exactly does the secret_key?

Comment: The secret key is used to encrypt your cookies